# How to remove item from List interface in java?

Tags: java

I have a `ArrayList`. When I try to remove an item I am getting an `UnsupportedOperationException`. How can I solve it? Please can any one help.

Here my code is:

```
static List<String> availableFormsList = new ArrayList<String>();
availableFormsList.add("a");   
availableFormsList.remove("a");
```

Comment: why is your list static?

Comment: is the list modified in any way (maybe differnet thread) in between the add and remove?

Comment: You should be getting compilation error for `static List<String> availableFormsList = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: I have used my list in another classes also that way i put it as a static.

Comment: why did you tag the question using _java_util_scanner_? there is no relation to that class in what you asked

Comment: Tried compiling your code, it compiles fine if you remove static keyword.

Comment: working fine with static keyword, no issue..

Comment: static, add and remove is not a problem. U shoud not assign like the "availableFormsList = Arrays.asList(answersList)" . use addAll method

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.ArrayList` supports removal of its elements. Check that `availableFormsList` is not being replaced with another implementation of `List` (such as that from `Arrays.asList`).

> I am using availableFormsList = Arrays.asList(answersList)

This renders replaces the `List` reference with a fixed size `List` from which elements cannot be removed. Solution: Don't replace `availableFormsList` with this `List`.

Comment: I am using availableFormsList = Arrays.asList(answersList);  for storing values in the list.

Comment: @user2466123 You can't remove from that `List` as `Arrays.asList` is of fixed size. Why use `Arrays.asList` if you already have a `List`?

Comment: @user2466123 that is not that you posted in the question!

Comment: Why the blanket downvoting?

Comment: +1 from me at least, simply for giving the *right* answer, anticipating that OP actually posted the wrong code.

Answer (score 1):

This works just fine:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * ListDemo
 * @author mduffy
 * @since 6/21/13 7:45 AM
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234415/how-to-remove-item-from-list-interface-in-java
 */
public class ListDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> availableForms = new ArrayList<String>();
        Collections.addAll(availableForms, args);
        System.out.println("before: " + availableForms);
        if (args.length > 0) {
            availableForms.remove(args[0]);
            System.out.println("after : " + availableForms);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `java ListDemo hello world`

Comment: The OP specifically asked about static variable.. I think it's more important to talk with respect to that. And obviously his code probably shouldn't even get compiled.

Comment: I think it's important to show how it works, and that's what I posted.  If you have an answer, please post it.  I don't need commentary.

Answer (score 0):

You might have another ArrayList declared by you?

```
public static class ArrayList<T> extends java.util.ArrayList<T> {

    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you've posted a different code from the one you're executing.

Comment: +1 You are on the right track here; actually, `Arrays.asList` returns an instance of a static nested class, named `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this??

```
    public class TestList {

        static List<String> availableFormsList = new ArrayList<String>();

        public static void main(String arg[]) throws Exception {

            String[] myStringArray = {"Java", "is", "Cool"};


            availableFormsList.addAll(Arrays.asList(myStringArray));
            availableFormsList.add("a");
            availableFormsList.remove("a");
            availableFormsList.add("Test");
            System.out.print("Test out put " + availableFormsList.toString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the OP specifically asked for the case where the variable is static, I'm going to add yet another answer.

```
public class Test {
    static List<String> availableFormsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */     
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        availableFormsList .add("a");
        System.out.println("Size: "+availableFormsList.size());
        availableFormsList.remove("a");
        System.out.println("Size: "+availableFormsList.size());
    }
}
```

And this doesn't throw any error.

EDIT: By now it's clear that OP missed out an important detail, namely, that he's using Arrays.asList() to generate the List.

Comment: If you've down-voted this answer, It'd be helpful to know why.